# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT token

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, objectmapper

How to read below `JSON` using `Jackson` `ObjectMapper`? I have developed code but getting below error.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (File); line: 7, column: 19] (through reference chain: com.example.demo.resources.Orgnization["secondaryIds"])
```

JSON

```
{
  "id": "100000",
  "name": "ABC",
  "keyAccount": false,
  "phone": "1111111",
  "phoneExtn": "11",
  "secondaryIds": {
    "ROP": [
      "700010015",
      "454546767",
      "747485968",
      "343434343"
    ],
    "AHID": [
      "01122006",
      "03112001"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show a [mre] with your Java entity and deserialization call to `ObjectMapper`.

Comment: May be you use: `mapper.readValue(is, List.class)` instead of `mapper.readValue(is, Map.class)`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to enable [ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY) feature. Probably in `POJO` you have a `List` but when there is only one element in a `List` `JSON` payload is generated without array brackets.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./src/main/resources/test.json");

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);

        Orgnization root = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, Orgnization.class);
        System.out.println(root);
    }
}
```