# Deserialize String as List of Strings

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a POJO that contains the following attributes

```
public class Example {
  @JsonProperty("inputFoo")
  private String foo
  @JsonProperty("inputBar")
  private String bar
  @JsonProperty("inputBaz")
  @JsonDeserialize(using = MyDeserializer.class)
  private Set<String> baz
}
```

The JSON that I am working with to represent this data currently represents the baz attribute as a single string:

```
{"inputFoo":"a", "inputBar":"b", "inputBaz":"c"}
```

I am using the Jackson ObjectMapper to attempt to convert the JSON to my POJO. I know that the input baz String from the JSON wont map cleanly to the Set that I am trying to represent it as, so I defined a custom Deserializer:

```
public class MyDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Set<String>> {
   public MyDeserializer(){}

   public MyDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
      super(vc);
   }

   public Set<String> deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext cxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
      String input = p.readValueAs(String.class);
      Set<String> output = new HashSet<>();
      if(input != null) {
         output.add(input);
      }
      return output;
   }
}
```

I am getting an IllegalArgumentException referencing the "inputBaz" attribute, which I can provide details on. Does anyone see any obvious issue with my deserializer implementation? Thanks

Comment: did you try getting rid of those constructors? `public class MyD extends StdDeser...{public Set<String> deserialize(...) throws ... {...}}`

Comment: you could try using `StringDeserializer.instance.deserialize(jp, dc)`

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to implement custom deserialiser, use [ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.11/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY) feature. It works for sets as well:

> Feature that determines whether it is acceptable to coerce non-array
> (in JSON) values to work with **Java collection (arrays,
> java.util.Collection) types**. If enabled, collection deserializers will
> try to handle non-array values as if they had "implicit" surrounding
> JSON array. This feature is meant to be used for
> compatibility/interoperability reasons, to work with packages (such as
> XML-to-JSON converters) that leave out JSON array in cases where there
> is just a single element in array. Feature is disabled by default.

See also:

- [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58539657/com-fasterxml-jackson-databind-exc-mismatchedinputexception-cannot-deserialize/58544375#58544375)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the 2 constructors with this no-arg constructor:

```java
public MyDeserializer() {
    super(TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(Set.class, String.class));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY` as suggested is a good option.

Maybe your actual problem is more complicated but if not you could also try `@JsonCreator` instead of custom deserializer. Like:

```
public class Example {

    @JsonCreator
    public Example(@JsonProperty("inputFoo") String foo,
            @JsonProperty("inputBar") String bar,
            @JsonProperty("inputBaz") String strBaz) {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.bar = bar;
        this.baz = new HashSet<>();
        baz.add(strBaz);
    }

    private String foo;
    private String bar;
    private Set<String> baz;
}
```

Just to show that in more general case you might avoid implementing custom deserializer with `@JsonCreator` also but still make some simple conversions.